# PowerSTIG For Microsoft Word, Excel, Powerpoint?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to understand how to use PowerSTIG from Microsoft. It seems so confusing. I just want to speed up running STIGS for Microsoft Word, Excel, PowerPoint. Is there an easier tutorial somewhere that could walk me through it? I cant seem to find one. I added the module to my machine using

```
Install-Module PowerSTIG -Scope CurrentUser
```

But then I am lost. What commands do I run for each of the Microsoft Office products?

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerStig

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerStig/wiki/GettingStarted#ia-review

Answer (score 1):

There is a function exposed via PowerSTIG, Get-Stig.  This function will return all valid STIG Technologies and their respective versions, so you know what is available with any release of PowerSTIG.  With this data, you can create several PowerSTIG configuration blocks to automate Office STIGs, an example configuration is listed below.  Once you have the .mof that's generated via this configuration, then you will have to use PowerShell DSC to apply the mof to the target.

```
Get-Stig -ListAvailable | ? Technology -like "*Office*"
```

```
configuration OfficeApps
{
    param()

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PowerSTIG

    Node localhost
    {
        Office system2016
        {
            OfficeApp = 'System2016'
        }

        Office excel2016
        {
            OfficeApp = 'Excel2016'
        }

        Office outlook2016
        {
            OfficeApp = 'Outlook2016'
        }

        Office powerpoint2016
        {
            OfficeApp = 'PowerPoint2016'
        }

        Office word2016
        {
            OfficeApp = 'Word2016'
        }
    }
}

OfficeApps -OutputPath C:\dev\
```

Comment: Brian thank you for your response. I will try this out. I am new to all this. This helps a lot. Thanks